# Correct usage of "visited upon"

Tags: meaning

In this sentence

> Human sophistication has significantly advanced since the Demons last visited upon them.

one proof-reader suggested removing the word "upon."

The speaker here has been around since biblical times and would be prone to use older language constructs. I want to connote with this sentence that the Demons are coming to Earth with the express purpose of committing harm.

Does the sentence make correct use of "visited upon"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase "visited upon" means "inflicted on", so it doesn't really make sense in the way that you are trying to use it. Your proof-reader's suggestion is reasonable. You could put "since the depredations of the Demons were last visited upon them."

> Alas, for the pitiful mote sins that we cannot express in words; for them that suffering is visited upon us here which we carry secretly on our wretched body.

The Flowing Light of the Godhead, Mechthild (of Magdeburg), tr. Frank J. Tobin

[Google Books Ngram Viewer: visited upon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=visited+upon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvisited%20upon%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: "Visited" alone doesn't imply menace. Can you think of a word or phrase that carries the implication that the demons are coming with malicious intent? (Ideally, something that feels archaic/biblical but is still well-understood by the modern reader)

Comment: @EricJ. See my edit.

Comment: @Eric _Visit_ alone can imply menace. If you have access to the OED, [senses 3.a–b, 5.a–c, and 6](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/223958?rskey=WIhljn&result=2) are all about inflicting punishment, avenging, requiting, harming, distressing, and even killing off. Sense 6 (the ‘absolute’ use) is exactly the construction you had here; the best quote, from the Douay-Rheims Bible (1610), Isaiah, XIII, 11: [“And I will visit the evils of the world, and against the wicked for their iniquity”](http://www.drbo.org/x/d?b=drb&bk=27&ch=13&l=11#x). So it’s old-fashioned, but your usage works.

Comment: @Eric Actually, an even more exact match is from Wycliffe’s Bible, Isaiah, X, 12: [“I shal **visite vpon** the fruyt of the gret doende herte of the king of Assur.”](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+10&version=WYC) (in the original quoted by the OED).

Answer (score 1):

"Therefore thus saith the Lord God of Israel against the pastors that feed my people; Ye have scattered my flock, and driven them away, and have not visited them: behold, I will **visit upon you** the evil of your doings, saith the Lord." ~ Jeremiah 23, v. 2.

Comment: I knew that there must be a biblical usage. I should have used a concordance. ;-)

Comment: In this sentence, **visit upon** correctly has "the evil of your doings" as the thing that is **visited upon** people. The example sentence in the user's question is trying (incorrectly) to do what this sentence does (i.e., sound biblical), but fails because the writer of the sentence doesn't have anything that is **visited upon** people. You don't **visit upon** people; you visit something upon them. So while this sentence is a good example of correct usage, it doesn't show that the original example sentence uses the phrase correctly.